# Can I compare to folders contents and return non-duplicate files?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I have a directory with a number of files. I have another directory with identical files, only now all the files are named the same but are within a folder that's named the same as the file names in the other directory.

Example:

First Directory `XYZ.txt, ABC.txt, LMN.txt`

Second Directory:`XYZ/text.txt, ABC/text.txt, LMN/text.txt`

I am looking to find out what files are present only in the second directory and not in the first.

How can i do this using the command line?

I've used the find command in both folders. The ABC.txt folder contains 870 files.

```
find . -name '*.txt' | egrep -f "*.txt"
```

While the second folder contains 109 Folders

```
find . -name 'text.txt' | egrep -c 'text.txt'
```

So I am expecting to find that maybe 80/90 of the 109 files are within the folder with 870 files.

I'm looking to find out which files are present in both directories and have them listed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no newlines in your file or directory names you could do something like:

```
diff \
    <(find first_dir -name '*.txt' -printf '%p\n' | sort) \
    <(find second_dir -name 'text.txt' | sed 's:.*/\([^/]*\)/[^/]*$:\1.txt:' | sort)
```

You might want to use `comm` instead of `diff`, idk.